# Bootstrap 4: TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined error

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, express, webpack, angular-universal

I have added Bootstrap 4  `"bootstrap": "^4.1.1"` into my angular 6 `SSR` app, but on running `node server.js` i get error below:

```
!(function(t,e){true?e(exports,__webpack_require__(150),__webpack_require__(255)):undefined})(this,(function(t,e,c){"use strict";function i(t,e){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var i=e[n];i.enumerable=i.enumerab
le||!1,i.configurable=!0,"value"in i&&(i.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,i.key,i)}}function o(t,e,n){return e&&i(t.prototype,e),n&&i(t,n),t}function h(r){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var s=null!=
arguments[t]?arguments[t]:{},e=Object.keys(s);"function"==typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols&&(e=e.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(s).filter((function(t){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(s,t).enum
erable})))),e.forEach((function(t){var e,n,i;e=r,i=s[n=t],n in e?Object.defineProperty(e,n,{value:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):e[n]=i}))}return r}e=e&&e.hasOwnProperty("default")?e.default:e
,c=c&&c.hasOwnProperty("default")?c.default:c;var r,n,s,a,l,u,f,d,_,g,m,p,v,E,y,T,C,I,A,D,b,S,w,N,O,k,P,L,j,R,H,W,M,x,U,K,F,V,Q,B,Y,

TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined
    at J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3538:2584
    at J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3538:2745
    at J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3538:22
    at Object.<anonymous> (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3538:94)
    at __webpack_require__ (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:1:360)
    at Object.module.exports (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3484:10746)
    at __webpack_require__ (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:1:360)
    at J:\Java\workstation\exhibition\front\.server\server.js:1:1654
    at Object.<anonymous> (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:1:1702)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
```

My vendor.ts:

```
window['jQuery'] = require('jquery');
window['$'] = window['jQuery'];  

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

webpack:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery', 
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  }),
```

Any idea about this error?

Comment: issue on github: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2406